How to make Azure OpenAI API GPT Batch calls in python
I have been trying to make batch calls to Azure OpenAI API to the GPT models and I couldn't find a tutorial so here is something I came up with (I am not a Software Engineer)

Minimum packages
pip install openai python-dotenv

Script:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) #Put everything in a .env file in the folder of the script or root of the project
from openai import AsyncAzureOpenAI
import asyncio

import nest_asyncio #used when in a notebook
nest_asyncio.apply() #used when in a notebook

client = AsyncAzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_ENDPOINT"), 
  api_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_KEY"),  
  api_version = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION")
)

async def get_single_response(message, client=client):
  response = await client.chat.completions.create(
                    model = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL_DEPLOYMENT"), # model deployment_name
                    messages = message,
                    temperature=1, #Let's get some variability
                    max_tokens=2400,
                    top_p=0.95,
                    frequency_penalty=0,
                    presence_penalty=0,
                    stop=None
                  )
  return message, response

async def get_batch_responses(messages):
    batch_responses = await asyncio.gather(*[get_single_response(j) for j in messages])
    return batch_responses

message_template = [
                    {"role": "system", "content":"You are an AI expert in OpenAI API and python"},
                    {"role":"user","content":"How can I make batch calls with Azure OpenAI API to GPT models in python?"}
                   ]

all_messages = [message_template]*5

results = asyncio.run(get_batch_responses(all_messages))

for i in range(len(results)):
    print(f"Call:{i+1}")
    print(results[i][0][1]['content'],end="\n\n")
    print(results[i][1].choices[0].message.content)
    print("-------")

